# Nothing showed when browsing ews Exchange.asmx

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Since yesterday, I tried to use the exchange web service but it was not able. Firstly when I was trying to access to the web service by the browser and the test program using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, there was an error **403 forbidden**. But this issue I solved by unchecking require SSL option in IIS. And now the problem is when I try to access on the ews using my program, I encounter **401 unauthorized** error, and if I try to browse the web service on the browser, only an empty page is returned (even when I browse the wsdl).
I tried to change the role and the password but it was not working.
Please help me to find out what I am missing.
Here is my test program code:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password, domain);
service.Url =new Uri("server/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(OnValidationCallback);
ExpandGroupResults groupResults = service.ExpandGroup(emailAddress);
```

The exception is on the last line

Comment: Some points that may help solve your issue : Are you using it from a console or web application ? Can you get your own calendar items using EWS ? If you browse to the asmx with Internet Explorer, do you see something ?

Comment: 1. My test program is Windows form application. 2. I can't get my calendar using EWS because I didn't success to connect to its functionality. 3. If I browse the asmx with Internet Explorer, nothing shows up but empty page.

Answer (score 1):

I found why the XML for the ews was not showing. It was because the IIS was not installed with basic authentication and Windows authentication. After installing those two authentication method, the web service shows its xml.
This is the link I referred: https://migrationwiz.zendesk.com/entries/506613-how-do-i-verify-ews-is-setup-properly